# disabled select tag doesn't have the color specified in css on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```css
select:disabled {
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
}
```

```html
<select disabled>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
```

If you run the code above on chrome and then check the background color of the select tag using a color picker you will get `#CFCFCF` and not `#BBBBBB`

Doing the same on a  tag works as expected, is this a bug in chrome or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` changes the item's opacity. add `opacity: 1;`

```css
select:disabled {
  background: #BBBBBB;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<select disabled>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This did the trick somewhat confusing that this is a thing...